# После нажатия на логотип открывается пустая страница

Tags: html, wordpress

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему происходит такая ситуация: если нажать на "лого", то открывается пустой экран?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте проблемный участок кода в тело вопроса. В случае нахождения и исправления ошибки ваш вопрос потеряет ценность для сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загляните в консоль браузера. Там масса ошибок скриптов. Но останов происходит вот на этой строке
document.getElementById("vk_api_transport").appendChild(el)
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null(…)

Это инициализация vk.

Почему при обычном обновлении страницы элемент DOM vk_api_transport создается раньше запуска скрипта, а при нажатии на лого - позже запуска скрипта, сказать сложно без детального анализа сайта.

Налицо явный конфликт скриптов.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!